# Core Data: A clever way to implement Add/Edit functionality

Tags: ios, core-data

I've created a couple of Apps that use Core Data and a lot of experiments, but I've never found the "perfect" way to implement a simple Add/Edit viewController. 
I just want to implement a single controller able to manage both the edit and add functionalities, I don't want to create two different Controllers.

At the moment I'm working whit this approach (let's take the classic `Person` `NSManagedObject` as example)

**1)**  In the `addEditViewController` I add a `currentPerson` property

```
var currentPerson:Person?
```

**2)** When I present the controller in `Add-Mode` this property is nil

**3)** When I present the controller in `Edit-Mode` this property is a reference to the Person to edit

**4)** When I need to save user operations I just check if the currentPerson is set and I understand if I need to create a new object in the context or just save the one I need to edit.

Ok, this approach works but I want to follow another approach that seems to be more secure for the edit action. Check this **terrible error**!

Let's say that the person has `Address` property that needs a different viewController to be edited.

**1)** Following my previous logic I can pass the `currentPerson` property to the `addressViewController` that I'm going to present:

```
addressVC.currentPerson = currentPerson
presentAddressVC()
```

**2)** Now when the user has completed the edit operation and he/she taps on "save"
the addressVC calls the `saveContext` function.

Where is the problem? well... if the user starts editing the `currentPerson` in the addEditViewController an then just goes back to a previous controller, the `currentPerson` still stores the edit of the user and as soon as the context will be saved in any other controller the not-really-wanted data get stored and becomes persistent.

Probably I can perform a `rollback` in case the user taps the back button on the addEditViewController, but I really don't like this behaviour it seems so poor.

I think to work with multiple contexts or inserting `NSManagedObjects` in a `nil` context and just move them to the main context only at the end of the operations but I'm not sure about this choice too.

I know it's a kind of a complex and long (an tedious) question, but I hope you can give me some lights on this issue. 
How to you treat this kind of situation? what do you think about my approach and about my proposed approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem is maintaining a connection to a single NSManagedObjectContext when instead what you really want is to establish a tree. The construction of a context is fairly cheap so you should be creating a context per ViewController.

So when you show the addEdit controller you can simply create it with a new context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
context.parentContext = //parentContext
context.undoManager = nil;
```

Think of these new contexts as scratch pads for editing your managed objects. The only thing to bear in mind is that when you call save, it saves to the parent context and not all the way to the store. For that you will need a recursive call all the way to the parent for saves. Heres a basic recursive save:

```
- (void)saveChangesToDiskForManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    if (context && [context hasChanges]) {
        [context save:nil];
         NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = context.parentContext;
         [parentContext performBlock:^{
            [self saveChangesToDiskForManagedObjectContext:parentContext];
         }];
    }
}
```

Its not really great practice to retain managed objects in an app where they could be deleted on other screens. So what you should do is perhaps fetch these objects in your view controllers view will appear method. Either that or call `refreshObject(mergeChanges:)` to synchronize your managed object with the changes made by another screen.

I really don't like the idea of calling `save` when the user navigates back, there should be a save button, when i press back I'm trying to close the screen, i would expect to select "done" if i want my changes saved.

Don't forget you can also use an NSUndoManager to track all your changes, thats why the context has an undoManager:)

Comment: Great answer. So to save this data to the store do I need to call save on the parent context? is it what you mean with "recursive call"?

Comment: @MatterGoal yip, thats the basic idea, will include a code snippet now